# How to encapsulate in English the parallelism between directional derivative and divergence?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, terminology

The directional derivative of a scalar field $f(x,y,z)$ at a point $P$ along a vector $
\mathbf v$ is the dot product of the gradient (vector differential operator):

$$\begin{align}
\nabla  &= \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial y},\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\end{bmatrix}^\top\\[2ex]
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\hat i+ \frac{\partial}{\partial y}\hat j + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}\hat k
\end{align}$$

applied to the function $f$

$$\nabla f = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f,\frac{\partial}{\partial y}f,\frac{\partial}{\partial z}f\end{bmatrix}^\top$$

and the vector $\mathbf v$:

$$D_{\mathbf v}f=\langle \nabla f, \mathbf v\rangle$$

---

The divergence is the dot product of the gradient operator $\nabla$ with a vector field $\mathbf F=\left(F_1(x,y,z),F_2(x,y,z),F_3(x,y,z)\right):$

$$\mathrm{div} \mathbf F=\nabla\mathbf F =\langle\nabla, \mathbf F\rangle$$

---

In English, the directional derivative compares a given vector to the direction of maximum steepness along a surface and at a given point, providing an idea of the change of the surface along the particular direction indicated by the vector.

The divergence quantifies the relative change in the vector field at a point.

Here are some parallelisms and differences:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&\small\text{Dir. Derivative}  & \small\text{Divergence} \\ \hline
\text{input}& \small\text{point & vector} &\small\text{point } \\ \hline
\text{output} & \small\text{scalar} & \small\text{scalar}\\ \hline
\text{defined on...} & \small\text{scalar field} &\small\text{vector field} \\ \hline
\text{operation} & \small\text{dot prod} &\small\text{dot prod} \\ \hline
\end{array}

Is there a way of getting an intuition in English of their similarities in concept or intention?

Comment: You have $\operatorname{div}{\mathbf{F}} = \sum_i \langle \mathbf{e}_i ,D_{\mathbf{e}_i} \mathbf{F} \rangle $ for any orthonormal basis $\{\mathbf{e}_i\}_i$: it's like a trace of the total derivative.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to find intuition for the divergence, I suggested considering physical situations. If one uses a vector field to describe the flow of a fluid. Then the divergence describes the sources and sinks of this fluid. On can get the flux through an closed surface (i.e. quantize the source or sink) by integrating the divergence.

Comment: Yes, the intuition for divergence is clear. The question is about the similarity of the two separate concepts of directional derivative and divergence.